# Java RCP: Create Extension point from existing extension

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, rcp

I'm currently using a Java application developed with Eclipse and RCP based; this application has few plugin files in jar format, these file are including special procedures for pricelist generation.

I need to develop a completely new application that uses the existing extensions to build new pricelist, so I created a new Plug-in project and I tried to create the Extension Point compatible with my existing extensions.

The problem is I'm not expert at all with RCP, so I made for sure some mistake: when I try to get the extension with this:

```
IExtensionRegistry reg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
IConfigurationElement[] extensions = 
reg.getConfigurationElementsFor("prices.year");

for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
    if(extensions[i].getName().equals("2016")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I always get 0 elements.

So for sure I made a mistake while creating the Extension point or when I added the available extension... or both!

Actually:
- I added the jar files in my project, then included in the build configuration
- I created the Extension point
- I open the .exsd file, added a "client" element with a "class" attribute; this class "Implements" field points to an object defined inside a jar class (the same object is implemented inside the plugin file)
[image: Eclipse window]
Inside the Plugin file (.jar) i have this:

```
public class Pricelist2017 extends Pricelist
 implements IPricedata
 {
   ...
```

-

EDIT:
After applying greg-449 suggestion, now I'm able to get some extension, but I face problem when I try to access them:

```
IExtensionRegistry reg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
IConfigurationElement[] extensions = reg.getConfigurationElementsFor("prices.year");

for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(extension[i].getName());
    System.out.println(extension[i].getAttribute("id"));
    System.out.println(extension[i].toString());
}
```

I get (for 2 extensions found):

```
client
null
prices.year.2016.Doc16@21b2e768

client
null
prices.year.2015.Doc15@313b2ea6
```

I'm missing something else, but it's tricky to find where to touch.
Many thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

So far you have just defined the extension point. That just makes the extension point available for use, it does **not** create any uses of the extension.

First make sure that your extension point definition defines how you use the `client` element. You need to have something like a `Sequence` in the `extension` section:
[image: Definition]

You must now create some uses of the extension point. In the 'Extensions' tab of the plugin.xml editor click 'Add...' and create an extension. This is where you specify the class that implements `IPricedata`:
[image: Extension]

Comment: Great. It works! So I absolutely need to know in advance how many classes are implementing IPricedata, then adding them one by one?
(actually I have few hundred classes that are implementing IPricedata, everyone with different attributes and I need to select them programmatically)

Comment: Yes, you need to create an extension for each class to do this using extension points.